# Как организуется серверная часть у хостинг провайдеров?

Tags: хостинг, vps, vds

Поделитесь опытом, как организуется разработка серверной части у хостинг провайдеров?
На чем ее пишут и какие инструменты для этого используют?

Под разработкой серверной части подразумеваю выделение серверных мощностей для клиентов, заказавших определенные услуги (shared-хостинг, VDS/VPS и др.).

Делается ли это вручную обслуживающим персоналом или все происходит автоматизированно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют системы автоматизации хостинг-провайдеров, я лично работал с несколькими - hspc(pba) - paralles, whmcs, ubersmith, onApp (это система автоматизации "облаков" на vps, с биллингом), все они жутко дороги как в покупке, так и в обслуживании. Для shared существуют такие панели, как Plesk, Cpanel, не помню, но вроде что-то было опенсорсное. Также, естественно, существуют некие системы, созданные провайдерами "под себя" (Amazon, Heroku). В больших датацентрах есть еще  и системы автоматизации физического обслуживания (от камер наблюдения до роборук на колесиках).

Вообще вопрос у вас слишком широкий, и если любопытство не праздное, то про половину вышесказанного вы уже и так знаете.